# Swift 3で特定のviewControllerのみで強制回転をしたい。

Tags: swift, swift3

アプリ起動時に、横画面にしたいと思い、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

と設定して、下のように書いても、viewControllerのみで強制回転できません。

ちなみに親にはコンテナビューコントローラーはありません。

シュミレーターで試しているだけということも関係あるかもしれません。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscape
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: 単独のView Controllerならば、ご提示のコードで画面方向の固定ができます。`UINavigationController`、`UITabBarController`などが親View Controllerになっている場合は、親の`supportedInterfaceOrientations`が優先になって、子のView Controllerの設定が無視されます。なので、アプリ全体のView Controllerの構成を説明いただくことが、必要になってくるでしょう。質問文の補足をお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！SingleViewのテンプレートでつくっただけなので、親には何もないです。シュミレーターで試しているだけということも関係あるかもしれません。

Comment: 実機でやったらうまくいきました！シュミレーターは回転しないのですね。

Comment: 以前のバージョンのXcodeならLandscapeオンリーのアプリをシミュレータで実行すると、シミュレータの初期表示も横長になっていたはずなのですが、現在のXcode(8.3.2でテスト)ではそのような動作にならないようです。ただ、アプリの画面を強制的にlandscapeにすると言うことは、ユーザがデバイスをどの向きに変えてもアプリの表示は画面を横長に使用すると言うことなので、シミュレータを使う場合でも画面を回転させて動作を確認しないといけません。

Comment: なるほど、たしかにそうですね！ありがとうございます！いまやったら、シュミレーターでも横表示になりました

Comment: やはりXc‌​ode8.3.2ではできなかったです！単にシュミレーターが回転していただけでした。失礼しました！